# C++/CLI Wrapper DLL TypeLoadException too many fields

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I have native (unmanaged) C++ DLLs that are being wrapped by a single C++/CLI dll (linking through the .lib files). These unmanaged C++ DLLs have quite a few classes with a ton of methods and a ton const data (e.g. strings, hex values, etc) which are defined in included headers.

But for the C++/CLI wrapper DLL its only a wrapping and marshalling layer for the native dll. However its binary size is as big as the native dll.
I believe this is causing me to hit the hardcoded limit which throws the exception when it is being loaded by a C# application:
**System.TypeLoadException: Internal limitation: too many fields**

The C# application will never use the fields defined in the headers for the native DLLs.

It was able to alleviate this issue through enabling of string pooling (shaving off a few MB), but it seems like a hack.

**Why is a simple wrapper of a DLL the same size as that DLL? Is there a way where I can mark the const data such that the C# application won't load them?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are falling into a pretty common trap, the C++/CLI compiler works too well.  It is capable of compiling any C++03 compatible native C++ code into IL when #pragma managed or /clr is in effect.  Works well at runtime too, it gets just-in-time compiled by the jitter to machine code, just like regular managed programs will be.

That's the good news.  The bad news is that this code does **not** execute like managed code.   It doesn't get verified and it doesn't get the garbage collector love.  It also doesn't run as efficiently as regularly compiled C++ code, you are missing out on the *extra* time that the C++ code optimizer has available get the absolute best possible machine code.

And the one restriction that made your program bomb.  Any global variables and free functions are compiled into members of the hidden `<Module>` class.  Required because the CLR doesn't support globals.  Members of a managed class get a metadata token, a number that uniquely identifies them in the metadata tables.  A token is a 32-bit value with the low 16-bits used to number them.  Kaboom when you created a `<Module>` class with more than 65535 members.

Clearly this is all quite undesirable.  You'll need to pay more attention to what code gets compiled to IL and what code gets compiled to machine code.  Your native C++ source code should be compiled **without** the /clr option in effect.  Shift+click select those files and set the option.  Where necessary, use #pragma un/managed to switch the compiler back and forth within one source code file.

Comment: Thanks.The native code is compiled without /clr support and packaged into a DLL. The C++/CLI wrapper is compiled with /clr support. Does this not work? The C++/CLI wrapper only has managed classes.

Comment: Well, that's not what the exception says.  Check your assumptions.  If you #include the header for the native C++ code in your C++/CLI source code files and they are not just plain C++ classes then you may need to wrap them in #pragma managed(push, off) and #pragma managed(pop) so the compiler knows that these headers contain unmanaged declarations.

Comment: I have DLLA.dll compiled with no clr support. DLLB.dll is linked to DLLA.dll with DLLA.lib. The VS2010 project for DLLB.dll includes header files used to build DLLA.dll. DLLB.dll has /clr support, and only contains ref classes which invoke functions from DLLA.dll. The C# application adds in DLLB.dll and invokes functions from the managed classes. I'm not sure where I am messing up. I'll try declaring these headers as unmanaged.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I found the issue and the wrapper dropped significantly in size. It was due to one of the legacy header files having a circular include with a headerfile that listed many header files. The codebase is poorly written, if you could not tell :). I'm not sure what the implications where with C++/CLI, but once i removed it, the file size dropped enormously.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is a simple wrapper of a DLL the same size as that DLL? Is there a way where I can mark the const data such that the C# application won't load them?

This is typically because you're compiling the entire project with `/CLR`.

If you're very careful to only include the absolute bare minimum requirements into the .cpp files which are compiled with /CLR, and only compile the .cpp files which are managed classes with /CLR, the wrapper projects tend to be far simpler and smaller.  The main issue is that any header that's used by a /CLR compiled .cpp file creates proxy types for all of the C++ types, which can explode into a huge number of fields or types in the assembly.

Using the [PIMPL idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) to "hide" the native code behind and opaque pointer can also dramatically shrink the number of types exposed to the managed portion of the assembly, as this allows you to not include the main headers within the managed code.